# resolving undefined issue with window.open and svg

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, svg

The script is supposed to take the **id** of a **path node** in the external svg file (the map of massachusetts) - each county is a 'path' labelled by an **id** tag. The script below can take the id of a path and when you click the county, its name appears in the console:

```
$(function(){

      var container = $("#map");
      var svgUrl    = "co25_d00.svg";

      $.get(svgUrl)
        .then(injectSvg);

      function injectSvg(xmlDoc) {

        var svg = $(xmlDoc).find("svg");
        container.append(svg);
        var clickLink = function() {
            window.open('http://www.google.com', '_top');
            };
        function alertId() {
            var county = $(this).attr('id');
            console.log(county);
            //window.open('https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/'+county+'_County,_Massachusetts', '_top');
        };
        $('path').click(alertId);
      }
    });
```

So it's able to grab that info out of the svg but now I can't figure out how to set that info to a variable to dynamically add to a url (in this case, a wikipedia article where variable "county" is the county id). This is where i'm at currently, and I'm getting "undefined":

```
$(function(){

  var container = $("#map");
  var svgUrl    = "co25_d00.svg";

  $.get(svgUrl)
    .then(injectSvg);

  function injectSvg(xmlDoc) {

    var svg = $(xmlDoc).find("svg");
    container.append(svg);
    var county;
    function getCounty() {
        var x = $(this).attr('id');
        return x;
        //window.open('https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/'+county+'_County,_Massachusetts', '_top');
    };
    var county = getCounty();
    function clickLink() {
        window.open('https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/'+county+'_County,_Massachusetts', '_top');
        };

    $('path').click(console.log(county));
  }
});
```

**Why am I getting undefined for county?**

Comment: Which variable is undefined?

Comment: var county is coming back as undefined

Comment: The `this` inside `getCounty()` is not bound to what you think it is.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi can you explain please?

Comment: That would be quite long -- the binding of `this` is one of the essential points of the JavaScript language. Essentially, by calling plain `getCounty()` you bind its inner `this` to `window` (or `undefined` in strict mode). It appears you think `this` would be bound to a DOM element (I don't know which one), but it is not the case.